# The use of "function setData ()" in the blocks on CMS pages

Tags: magento-1.9, template, cms-block

I can not understand why variable transmission does not work, when the block is called, the display categories on the home page.
in the template file I pass a variable to a different template file

**list.phtml**

```
<?php $this->getChild('icon_labels')->setData('product', $_product); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('icon_labels', false); ?>
```

if you go into the category of a direct link, then everything works, but if you call category, for example, on the home page

```
{{Block type = "catalog / product_list" template = "catalog / product / list.phtml" category_id = "52" toolbar_block_name = "product_list_toolbar"}}
```

I receive an error that Fatal error: Call to a member function setData () on a non-object in \ list.phtml on line

why this error, I can not understand ..
I would be grateful for your help. Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced this code

```
<?php $this->getChild('icon_labels')->setData('product', $_product); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('icon_labels', false); ?>
```

on this code in file list.phtml

```
<?php 
echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
 ->setData('product', $_product)
 ->setTemplate('catalog/product/icon_labels.phtml')
 ->toHtml(); 
?>
```

This block in addition, it works well when called list.phtml file from anywhere. And does not require an update of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

on the category page, the icon_labels block seems to be added due to a layout update.

but with the `{{Block type = "catalog / product_list" template = "catalog / product / list.phtml" category_id = "52" toolbar_block_name = "product_list_toolbar"}}` directive you add only the catalog/product_list block without any child blocks.

So in the phtml the `$this->getChild('icon_labels')` returns null and thats why you get the error. The Block icon_labels is not added as a child block here.

The block icon_labels is most likely is added in a layout.xml file in your theme. To have access to it in your CMS page you have to add it to the product_list block there first

Comment: Thank you, you helped me to understand the nature of the error.