# How to pass a block with 2 variables (in a CMS page) to a phtml file?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, frontend

I have some block in CMS page, I want to move it in `.phtml` file, but I don't know how to parse these variables(`category_id="12"`, `count_products="4"`), and from where these variables are coming? from a block right ?

**CMS block:**

```
{{block type="products/blocks_products" category_id="12" count_products="4" template="custom/list2.phtml"}}
```

**.phtml:**

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('products/blocks_products')->setTemplate('custom/list2.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking refrence to [This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101676/the-use-of-function-setdata-in-the-blocks-on-cms-pages) post

you can also pass array in setData function

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('products/blocks_products')
           ->setData(array('category_id'=>'12' , 'count_products'=>'4')) //for one data use setData('category_id', '12') 
           ->setTemplate('custom/list2.phtml')
           ->toHtml();
```

Supposing that if you have just one variable,then no need to put array,
Just use `setData('category_id', '12')`

Comment: supposing that I have just one variable, I will put it in an array ? `setData(array('category_id'=>'12'))`

Comment: @Prince then you can do `setData('category_id', '12')`

Comment: @Prince you are always welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way:

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('products/blocks_products')
    ->setCategoryId('12')
    ->setCountProducts('4')
    ->setTemplate('custom/list2.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

I haven't tested but should work.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832906/pass-a-variable-to-a-template-phtml-block-in-magento)